# How to find overlap interval of two objects moving parallel in opposite direction

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics

If two objects, let's say 2 trains, both of which are 10m in length, are moving on tracks parallel to each other, but each train is moving in the opposite direction. The first train is moving 5 m/s  and the second train is moving 7 m/s. How do I find the amount of time that each train "overlaps" (Let's say, the time frame in which passengers from one train can see passengers in the other train)

Comment: Hint: same time as if one train stood still while the other one passed by it at $5+7 = 12 \,\text{m/s}\,$.

Comment: Change the frame of reference. Make one train stationary and the second train move faster.

Comment: With those hints, perhaps you can add some thoughts of your own (I recommend to edit the question to add new things rather than trying to work this out in comments) that will lead to further answers.